# Does pre-processing run in parallel via dask?

Tags: python-xarray

I am loading many netCDF4 files like so:

```
theDataset=xr.open_mfdataset(input_files,
                             concat_dim='time',
                             preprocess=preprocess_dims,
                             chunks={'time':chunk_size})
```

The preprocessing function subsets the dataset and drops a coordinate.

My question is, does xarray do this pre-processing in parallel as with other Dask operations?

It is taking much longer than a

```
multiprocessing.pool
```

and the print statements inside the preprocessing function look like they are from a single core.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docstring for `open_mfdataset` it should do if you pass `parallel=True`.

[Here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1981) is the github pull request where parallel opening and preprocessing in `open_mfdataset` was implemented, I suggest you have a read.